# Solve $\frac{x}{m}=\lfloor{x^{2/3}}\rfloor+ \lfloor{x^{1/2}}\rfloor+1$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Prove that for every natural number $m$ there is a natural solution for the eqation $\frac{x}{m}=\lfloor{x^{2/3}}\rfloor+ \lfloor{x^{1/2}}\rfloor+1$

Beside the typical inequality I can't get nothing from it

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The set

$$\left\{x\,\bigg |\, \frac{x}{m} \geq \left\lfloor{x^{2/3}}\right\rfloor+ \left\lfloor{x^{1/2}}\right\rfloor+1  \right \}$$
is non-empty, thus must have a smallest element.

Let $k$ be the smallest element.

Now use that $k \neq 0$ and $k-1$ not in the set, to prove that for $k$ you must have equality. To do this, multiply both sides by $m$, and observe that if you have strict inequality, the difference must be at least one. Do this for $k$ and $k-1$.

Comment: Is $x \in \mathbb{N}$ neccessary for your set?

Comment: @mvw: It’s the fact that the set is a subset of $\Bbb N$ that allows N. S. to conclude that the set has a smallest element.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I was not sure about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plot for $m=3$
[image: floor vs non-floor vs x/3]

One notices from the different growth types that there must be a common point between the floored function and $x/m$ and that this one has a natural number as value.

But not why $x$ should be a natural number as well. (Or is just $x/m$ asked to be shown natural?)

Comment: Both, m and x, need to be natural